# Scaling Core Graphics stroke paths with CPTScatterPlot

Tags: core-plot

I have a data set I am plotting as a CPTScatterPlot. I am also displaying a series of lines using Core Graphics (CGContextStrokePath, ...). I would like to link the set of lines and scatter plot such that they scale and pan together. Below is a link to the reference image.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2pq2bdx.jpg

There are two possible approaches to this that I can think of:

1. Create a CPTLayerAnnotation for the set of lines and add to the plot. I have done this but I cannot link the interaction behavior.
2. Make each line a CPTScatterPlot object and plot on the same graph. This would work but seems to be overkill in terms of the number of objects created.

What would you suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a scatter plot to draw the lines, but you'd need one for each color. You can draw multiple line segments with a single scatter plot by separating the segments with a data value of `[NSNull null]` or `nil`.

It would be easiest to use a bar plot to draw the lines. You can use the `-barLineStyleForBarPlot:recordIndex:` and/or `-barFillForBarPlot:recordIndex:` datasource methods to provide a different line style and fill for each bar. The bar plot can use the same plot space as the scatter plot or you can create a second one and mirror changes in one plot space to the other with a plot space delegate. Use the second plot space if you want the spacing between the bars (controlled by the `xRange` of the plot space) to change with the scatter plot, but not the base or tip of the bars.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I am glad that CPTBarPlot could be used here. I created a class to encapsulate a CPTBarPlot object and two NSMutableArrays for the locations and correctness of responses. I utilized the data source methods to plot the bars, with transparent border lines. `barFillForBarPlot:recordIndex` was written to return the required (green or red) color to the barFill depending on the correctness array values. I am using the same plot space for the scatter and bar plots as of now since I would be restricting the vertical scaling and panning all together.